# How to create a REST Paypal Payment with Third-party payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to create a Paypal Payment using its REST API (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/paypal-payments/), but I couldn't find out how to send the payment to a third-party Paypal business account. 
Is it possible using the REST API? 
I know this can be done using Paypal SDK for Asp.net, but unfortunately there's no sdk available for asp.net core.
Thanks, 
  Bruno.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is possible to do by setting the `payee`. Please see https://devblog.paypal.com/setting-payee/